# DevTools failed to parse SourceMap error after login will redirect to that js file

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am new to VueJS. I am following one of the YouTube tutorial Let's Build a Multi-Purpose Laravel + Vue Application by Code Inspire

This is his github package.
https://github.com/Hujjat/laravStart

I notice. When I logout and login again, it will redirect to .js file.

for my case:-
http://laravel-vuejs.test/js/popper.js.map

and I clone his project. I tried with inspect, I login and logout and login. It will redirect to
http://laravstart.test/js/laravel-vue-pagination.common.js.map

It will show 404 error. I have every time remove the /js/xxxx.js.map then only back to normal.
[image]

Both of my project, when I run inspect. I notice have the Chrome warning.

DevTools failed to parse SourceMap: http://laravstart.test/js/laravel-vue-pagination.common.js.map

DevTools failed to parse SourceMap: http://laravel-vuejs.test/js/laravel-js/popper.js.map

*IMPORTANT NOTE* It only happen when I open the chrome inspect windows. If I close it, it will back to normal means won't redirect to JS file.

Screen record: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vV3G9.jpg

I tested with Chrome and Firefox with inspect both having the same problem.

But in Chrome if I off setting for source map, it will not have this issue.

[image]

Anyone how to fix it? Compile source map issue? the js.map file not exist.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found that one solution is created a dummy file at `public/js/popper.js.map`, then it will back to normal, basically just fulfil what browser developer tool required, it will not redirect to that specific file.

I believe this is browser developer tools behaviour.

I received solution from the laraStart repo owner.

> This error happens when you have an error and compile your javascript
>   code. Later, when you fix it, it will remain in cache and happens.
>   Please try to compile your script again and login to see.

The solution is also working as well.

I run `npm update` and `npm run dev`, it is working fine.

Comment: Hey man! I've got the exact same issue! I trie npm update and npm run dev, and it persists. As you mentioned it only happens if I have devtools open. Did you figure it out? I mean, creating a dummy file seems kinda wierd, but if its the only solution I'll go for it I guess. Thanks!

Comment: My solution it work in first two days, after that it does not work. For me create the dummy file is the easy solution. Funny bug but annoying...

Comment: Ye, that solution did work for me as well... This is probably the first bug I can't really find any real solution, as your solution does work seems kind of a work around :) But thanks !

Answer (score 30):

If you use Laravel Mix, you can generate source maps by calling the mix.sourceMaps() method in your webpack.mix.js file.
This resolves the problem.

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').sourceMaps();
```

[Laravel Mix Source Maps documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mix#css-source-maps)

Answer (score 4):

Open "find in files", find every commented line of code that has

```
sourceMappingURL=...
```

Delete the whole commented line for each.

There should be 3 entries here in public/app.js and 1 at the end of popper.js.

If you are using Brave shields or an ad blocker, turn it off

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is just copy the popper.js.min from

node_modules
 - popper.js
   -  dist
    ->  popper.js.min

this solved my headache

Answer (score 1):

There are two SourceMap error in my case so the two previous answers applied to me. 
1) By adding sourceMaps() in the mix.js function in webpack.mix.js file

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').sourceMaps();
```

to remove popper.js source map error.

2) Adding toastr.js.map to public/js folder to remove toastr.js source map error.